# Meaning of a Feynman diagram in proof of Ward-Takahashi identity in chapter 7 of Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, ward-identity

I'm trying to understand what the external photon in this diagram (page 238 in P&S) corresponds to exactly. This diagram is supposed to be a contribution to the Fourier transform of a QED correlation function (P&S denote this entire object as "$\textit{M}(k)$"). It seems to me from reading page 217 that the external electron lines correspond to electron propagators, so I assume the external photon corresponds to a photon propagator (rather than a polarization vector for that photon). The uncontracted Lorentz index in that propagator would then correspond to the index of the photon field in the correlation function, so this interpretation seems to make sense. But then two issues arise:

1. The "$\textit{M}(k)$" should carry that index too, yet the notation of P&S seems to suggest that this object is a scalar since it has no Lorentz indices.
2. Furthermore, I don't see how it is possible to factor out a polarization vector "$\epsilon_\mu(k)$" as they go on to do, where would it come from if that external photon corresponds to a photon propagator rather than a photon polarization vector?

[image]